# How to bind a ReactiveCommand to a control in a Xamarin.Forms ListView?

Tags: xaml, reactiveui, xamarin.forms

I am using ReactiveUI, Xamarin.Forms and XAML. I am trying to implement a simple scenario with a ListView where each row has a delete button. Here is the ListView XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="playerListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Players}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="20, 5, 20, 5">
                    <Label Text="{Binding .}" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
                    <Button x:Name="deleteButton" Text="Delete" Clicked="onDeleteClicked"  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

As you can see, the delete button has a Clicked handler registered. This works but it does not feel like the RxUI way. Here is the code behind:

```
    private void onDeleteClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var button = (Button)sender;            
        this.ViewModel.RemovePlayer.Execute(button.BindingContext);                
    }
```

How can I replace this onDeleteClicked event handler with a declarative binding to my RemovePlayer command? I can't see a good way to do it because I chose to bind the ListView to a `ReactiveList<string>`, so if I try to do `Command="{Binding RemovePlayer}"` it fails because the cell is bound to a string.

For completeness here is my view model:

```
public class NewGameViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    public ReactiveList<string> Players { get; private set; }
    public ReactiveCommand<Object> AddPlayer { get; private set; }
    public ReactiveCommand<Object> RemovePlayer { get; private set; }
    public ReactiveCommand<Object> StartGame { get; private set; }
    public ReactiveCommand<Object> RandomizeOrder { get; private set; }

    string newPlayerName;
    public string NewPlayerName {
        get { return newPlayerName; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref newPlayerName, value); }
    }

    public NewGameViewModel()
    {
        Players = new ReactiveList<string> ();

        var canStart = this.Players.CountChanged.Select(count => count >= 3);
        StartGame = canStart.ToCommand();
        RandomizeOrder = canStart.ToCommand();          

        AddPlayer = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Players.Count, x => x.NewPlayerName, 
            (count, newPlayerName) => count < 7 && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newPlayerName) && !this.Players.Contains(newPlayerName))
            .ToCommand();

        RemovePlayer = ReactiveCommand.Create();            
    }
}
```

Comment: i have this same question. how might one accomplish this in reactiveui 7.0?  ```ReactiveCommand.Execute()``` is no longer there?  should i just use reglar xamarin forms commands for relative binding situatiuons?

Answer (score 3):

Because there is no relative binding support in Xamarin Forms at the moment (see [this Xamarin Forms forums post for more info](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/68059#Comment_68059)), you won't be able to bind a command to your `Button` within your `ListView`s `DataTemplate`. Any binding within that `DataTemplate` will have a `BindingContext` relative to the current item in the list - in your case, a simple `string`. If your `ListView` was bound to an object, let's say a `Person`, then your `Button` command binding would still fail with an error something along the lines of *No Command `RemovePlayer` found on object `Person`*

So implementing the `Command` in the view's code behind like you have done is one option. Another is using a C# `DataTemplate` (not a XAML one) and implementing the `Command` there - but both of those are kind of the same thing. Neither are a great solution if you like keeping stuff like that **out** of your views and only within your view models; but until relative binding support is introduced there aren't really any other options.

I ran into the exact same problem as you, but I was binding my `ListView` to a collection of objects. The class for my object was in a separate class library that ONLY has POCOs in it, and I did not like the idea of implementing a `Command` within one of my POCO's.

Answer (score 2):

The tricky bit is that your "SelectedPlayer" isn't exposed in your ViewModel, so there's no way to do this the RxUI way. If it was, you can do something like:

```
RemovePlayer.Select(_ => SelectedPlayer).Subscribe(x => {
    SelectedPlayer = null;
    Players.Remove(x);
});
```

If your Player object was itself a ViewModel and "RemovePlayer" was on the Player itself, you can do this Tricky Trick:

```
Players.Changed.StartWith(null)
    .Select(_ => Players
        .Select(x => x.RemovePlayer.Select(__ => x))
        .Merge())
    .Switch()
    .Subscribe(x => Players.Remove(x));
```

Here, we're saying, "Every time the Players list changes, I want to build a new Observable: Take the list of all the *current players*, and Select them into an Observable that fires when someone hits a RemovePlayer button - tell me when *any* of those new Observables fire"

Comment: Just focusing on the first part of your answer for now: I'm happy to add a SelectedPlayer to my viewmodel, but how would that help? Specifically: 1. How would my RemovePlayer command get triggered? 2. How would my SelectedPlayer get updated on my ViewModel when the delete button is tapped? Are you assuming that the delete button would only be visible on the selected row?

Comment: Oops, I misread the code a bit, I assumed there was a single RemovePlayer button, not one-per-item. You can go with just the plain Event hook approach, or I would make Player a ViewModel in that case

Answer (score 0):

My opinion on this is don't be a purist :)

Is not the best design model, but extend your object to handle a ICommand and bind to it.. it's the best solution for now imo.

If your objects are on the same assembly you can use partial's , if are different , you can create small viewmodel for your poco .